# Is "--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled" supposed to set navigator.webdriver to false?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I've been reading how bot programmers are getting around bot detection techniques, and one of the main ones is to have their bots launch Chrome (typically Chromium) with `--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled`. This then sets `navigator.webdriver` to `false`, even though it should be `true`.

I'm trying to find documentation or git commit messages on why `--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled` was added to Chrome, and if its intended goal is to set `navigator.webdriver` to `false`, but I'm struggling to find anything. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Just to clear up some misconceptions...

**navigator.webdriver** should return **undefined** in human browsers, and **true** in automated (bots).

If upon checking a visitor you’re getting a **false** then it should be a bot that has hacked the navigator object or something because ideally, a well disguised bot should return **undefined** so as not to arouse suspicion.

The flag ***--disable-blink-features*** is exactly what it says... a general purpose mechanism for disabling an array of things for test purposes.

The ***AutomationControlled*** is what you should be researching because it controls the EXPOSURE of three bot-related flags:

***--enable-automation***
***--headless***
***--remote-debugging-port***

Once this exposure has been disabled via…

***--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled***

...then **navigator.webdriver** should return **undefined** for all browsers (manual/auto) regardless.

Make of it what you will...